# Homology of the $n$-sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I know the computation of $H_*(S^n)$, but I do not understand what the following theorem means:

“For any integer $n\ge 0$, $H_*(S^n)$ is a free abelian group **with two generators, one in dimension $0$ and one in dimension $n$.**” What generators does this theorem refer to?

Comment: It means $H_0(S^n)\cong\Bbb Z$, $H_n(S^n)\cong\Bbb Z$  and all other $H_i(S^n)$ vanish.

Comment: I was confused because $H_0(S^0)=\mathbb Z+ \mathbb Z$

Comment: That's the exceptional case...

Comment: Thanks for your illustration @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Note that $H_*(S^0)$ is still free on 2 generators so your boldfaced statement is still true.

Comment: Yes I got it. At first I thought the dimension in the theorem refers to the power of the sphere and it led me to confusion since if the power is zero there are two generators in this sense of dimension, not one generator @Randall

Comment: The statement only makes sense if you understand $H_*(S^n) = \bigoplus_{i= 0}^\infty H_i(S^n)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes it is the precise answer thanks